# Find objects of type including subclasses of that type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance

Suppose I'm trying to get all objects of type `A`, which inherits from `MonoBehaviour`:

```
A[] as = FindObjectsOfType<A>();
```

Suppose there are classes `B` and `C` that inherit from `A`.

Is there a similar method that also includes all objects of type `B` and `C`?

Comment: An array declared as `A[]` can only contain objects of type `A` or their descendants. How do you expect to put instances of `B` and `C` into it? Are they descendants of `A`?

Comment: @JohnWu as mentioned in the question, `B` and `C` inherit from `A`.

Comment: that's the default behaviour of `FindObjectsOfType` anyway ....

Comment: I had a very unusual problem at my testing that caused this method to seem like it was not catching subclasses of the base type. After deeper testing it worked but I could not delete the question anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the base type and FindObjectsOfType will grab all instances of that Type including types inheriting that Type.

```
 public class TypeA : MonoBehaviour {}
 public class TypeB : TypeA {}

 var objects = FindObjectsOfType<TypeA>(); // will include TypeB as well
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't this help? They are the heirs.

```
MonoBehaviour[] as = FindObjectsOfType<A>().Concat(FindObjectsOfType<B>()).Concat(FindObjectsOfType<C>());
```

Comment: It could help if I had just a few classes but the question was simplified, I have a lot of classes which inherit from A and there will be even more in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Then you may need a method that will return all the objects and filter them, but it will most likely be expensive.

Try this:

```
.Where((x=> typeof(x).BaseType == typeof(A)) || (x=>typeof(x) == typeof(A)))
```